# combo box not not adding id to option value

Tags: php, html

dropdown box is not adding the $id to the value=/customer when selected and goes to the url. It just shows the /customer page but would like it to show .../customer$id as to load their specific page. Thank you for your help

```
<select type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer Lookup" onchange="window.location=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
<option>Customers</option>
<?php

require ('dbconnect.php');
$result = $con->query("select id, lastname, firstname from customer");

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

unset($id, $name);
$id = $row['id'];
$name = $row['lastname'];
$firstname = $row['firstname']; 

echo '<option value="/customer"'.$id.'">'.$name.','.$firstname.'</option>';

}

echo "</select>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: One quote too many, do `<option value="/customer'.$id.'">`

Comment: @Fred-ii- ugh you always win. :P

Comment: This one's all yours @Darren Bonus points ;)

Comment: Protip: When debugging (you are, right?), always check your HTML source to pinpoint the "source" of the problem while adding error reporting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue lies here:

```
echo '<option value="/customer"'.$id.'">'.$name.','.$firstname.'</option>';
                              ^
```

You're closing off the `value` attribute with that extra **`"`**.

Do this instead.

```
echo '<option value="/customer'.$id.'">'.$name.','.$firstname.'</option>';
```

Comment: thanks guys my eyes are broken :)